# Mongoose/mongo query for date range and multiple text strings in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Does anyone know if it is possible to query by date range and search mutliple text fields at the same time?

Here is my query witch is only working without date range. But when I add date range it fails.

```
const searchQuery = {
      $or: [
        { msg: new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { name: new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'err.stack': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'req.statusCode': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'req.method': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'req.headers': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'res.header': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        { 'res.statusCode': new RegExp(query, 'i') },
        {  time: { $gte: gte, $lte: lte } },
      ],
    };
```

And it works querying by date range if I set time only.

But does not query by both as I was hoping for.

Is this possible and what am I then doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? What is the expected and actual outcome?

Comment: I get no documents from query. But if I do either date range or text query separately then I receive desired document from db

Comment: If I for example remove the time query object and then I get one docuement from db as desired and if I have only time object I get one docuement as well. #tbking